# Turn vector output into columns in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am generating output by applying function to some subsets of data.table. I am using function like this:

```
data[, foo(args), by=list(Year, Month)]
```

My function `foo` return always a vector of length `n`. I am getting an output like this:

```
      Year Month           V1
   1: 1983     2 9.734669e-06
   2: 1983     2 9.165665e-06
   3: 1983     2 2.097477e-05
   4: 1983     2 3.803727e-05
```

But I would like something like

```
      Year Month           V1           V2           V3           V4 ...
   1: 1983     2 9.734669e-06 9.165665e-06 2.097477e-05 3.803727e-05 ...
```

I even tried using `list(foo(args))`, it didn't help. Or should the output be in form `foo$V1, foo$V2 ...`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
data[, as.list(foo(args)), by=list(Year, Month)]
```

or change `foo` to return a `list` rather than a `vector`.